# How to validate contents of a CSV file using Django forms

Tags: django, csv, django-forms

I have a web app that needs to do the following:

1. Present a form to request a client side file for CSV import.
2. Validate the data in the CSV file or ask for another filename.

At one point, I was doing the CSV data validation in the view, after the `form.is_valid()` call from getting the filename (i.e. I have the imported CSV file into memory in a dictionary using `csv.DictReader`). After running into problems trying to pass errors back to the original form, I'm now trying to validate the CONTENTS of the CSV file in the form's `clean()` method.

I'm currently stumped on how to access the in memory file from `clean()` as the `request.FILES` object isn't valid. Note that I have no problems presenting the form to the client browser and then manipulating the resulting CSV file. The real issue is how to validate the contents of the CSV file - if I assume the data format is correct I can import it to my models. I'll post my forms.py file to show where I currently am after moving the code from the view to the form:

```
forms.py

import csv
from django import forms
from io import TextIOWrapper


class CSVImportForm(forms.Form):
    filename = forms.FileField(label='Select a CSV file to import:',)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CSVImportForm, self).clean()
    
        f = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['filename'].file, encoding='ASCII')
        result_csvlist = csv.DictReader(f)
        # first line (only) contains additional information about the event
        # let's validate that against its form definition
        event_info = next(result_csvlist)
        f_eventinfo = ResultsForm(event_info)
        if not f_eventinfo.is_valid():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Error validating 1st line of data (after header) in CSV")
    
        return cleaned_data

class ResultsForm(forms.Form):
    RESULT_CHOICES = (('Won', 'Won'),
                      ('Lost', 'Lost'),
                      ('Tie', 'Tie'),
                      ('WonByForfeit', 'WonByForfeit'),
                      ('LostByForfeit', 'LostByForfeit'))

    Team1 = forms.CharField(min_length=10, max_length=11)
    Team2 = forms.CharField(min_length=10, max_length=11)
    Result = forms.ChoiceField(choices=RESULT_CHOICES)
    Score = forms.CharField()
    Event = forms.CharField()
    Venue = forms.CharField()
    Date = forms.DateField()
    Div = forms.CharField()
    Website = forms.URLField(required=False)
    TD = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

I'd love input on what's the "best" method to validate the contents of an uploaded CSV file and present that information back to the client browser!

Comment: How do you activate python code high-lighting?

Comment: Is not python code highlighting. Is *general* code highlighting. That is accomplished by indexing all you want to declare as code four spaces. That is Markdown markup language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that when you want to access that file is in this line inside the `clean` method:

```
f = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['filename'].file, encoding='ASCII')
```

You can't use that line because `request` doesn't exist but you can access your form's fields so you can try this instead:

```
f = TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data.get('filename'), encoding='ASCII')
```

Since you have done `super.clean` in the first line in your method, that should work. Then, if you want to add custom error message to you form you can do it like this:

```
from django.forms.util import ErrorList
errors = form._errors.setdefault("filename", ErrorList())
errors.append(u"CSV file incorrect")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in responding - I was out of town for a long weekend and didn't get to work on this.
This worked after adding .file:
f = TextIOWrapper(self.cleaned_data.get('filename').file, encoding='ASCII')